# how to increase the orientation speed for iPad?

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation

I'm using orientation for my application in iPad. i need to increase my orientation speed while i do the orientation(landscape, portrait, portrait upsidedown, landscape left, landscape right). but it little bit slow when orient the view can you please give the solution for my issue.

edit:

i have two controller landscape and portrait while orientation i just call the method for orientation and load the method

Comment: Are you executing some code when the orientation changes?  Show a sample or describe in more detail what the code does and in what delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution sorry for not post the answer try to use the UIView as temp view and show that view while orientation is take place it looks pretty good to see... i solved it